# How would national ranked voting or approval voting (cumulative voting?) affect US elections?

Tags: united-states, voting-systems

The first-past-the-post voting system that is primarily used in the USA has resulted in a two party system with a very large number of voters practicing tactical voting. This has caused some voters to give up on voting for some offices since they view both parties as equally bad, possibly in different ways, and their preferred candidates have no chance of winning.

If all the Green Party votes had gone to the Democrats in 2016, Hillary would have won. But that can't be done in the current first-past-the-post system.

So that leads to the question, if all the States switched to a better voting system that gives voters more choice, such as approval voting, or ranked voting (instant runoff), or a runoff election, how would that change the parties? If that would mean that other parties such as the Green Party or the Libertarian party would now have a chance of making it to the final runoff (last two candidates) in a runoff election, or doing so virtually in an instant runoff election, or coming in 2nd in the approval voting system, then that would break the Republican and Democrat two party rule.

Could the Libertarian party beat the Democrats in a final runoff? What party would be best suited to beat the Republicans?

Which of these systems would have the best chance of ending the two party system? One advantage of having a runoff election with at least two elections is that the candidates can readjust their campaigns based on who they are running against.

**Definitions:**

**First-past-the-post:** A system where all voters get only one vote to use on one candidate. The candidate with the most votes wins. This is what is done in most of the English speaking world.

**Approval voting:** Voters can approve multiple candidates on the ballot. The candidate with the most approvals wins. To say it another way, voters get multiple votes, but can only use the additional votes on different candidates, and no candidate can receive more than one vote. The candidate with the most votes wins.

**Runoff election:** Voters vote at least two times. Each time the running candidates are reduced to a smaller group. You cannot write in a candidate who has been eliminated. It normally ends in a final runoff where only two candidates remain. The candidates get to change their campaign strategies based on who they are running against after each runoff.

**Ranked voting or instant runoff:** Voters vote for candidates in order of most preferred to less preferred. This simulates a runoff election, but it is all done when counting the ballots. Candidates are reduced to smaller numbers and the ballots are counted again, with voters' lower ranked candidates being used if their other choices have been eliminated.

**Cumulative voting:** This sounds like approval voting, but it's actually not. With cumulative voting, voters can simply split their votes between multiple candidates. It is statistically equivalent to randomly choosing between two or more choices in a traditional first-past-the-post election. Some voters are uninformed or get confused and treat it like an approval voting system, so it can act like the approval voting system in these cases. It's just a sham recreation of the first-past-the-post system.

**Tactical voting:** The practice of voting for a candidate who is likely to win to prevent another candidate from winning, instead of voting for the most preferred candidate.

Comment: You're asking us to predict the future, which is out of scope for this SE, and also out of scope for all political science.  We can barely make predictions from one election to the next, much less what it would look like to totally revamp our election system.

Comment: Are you asking about just the presidential election?  Or House and Senate elections as well?  Should we assume that the Electoral College is still in place for the presidential election?  Because that's going to make most of the changes moot.

Comment: This question is about how the different voting systems mentioned would affect the outcome of elections. Which system would be most likely to end the two party system? It's an open ended question that's about not just the presidential election but other offices as well. The question that is marked as already answered only addresses the IRV system. This question is about how the IRV and approval and runoff systems would change things differently.

Comment: @Justin Cave, you're right about the Electoral College. That breaks the many of the alternative voting systems. The Green Party could win in Maine where they have IRV and that victory would end up just changing which of the two parties win the presidential election. But the question is still valid regarding elections for the House and Senate.